# i am writing a code to make a simple web browser using VS 2010 in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.ComponentModel;    
using System.Data;    
using System.Drawing;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Text;    
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyWebBrowser
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MyWebBrowser.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> The type or namespace name 'Navigate' does not exist in the namespace 'MyWebBrowser' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: /*i m getting this error -->The type or namespace name 'Navigate' does not exist in the namespace 'MyWebBrowser' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
*/

Comment: Change `MyWebBrowser` to your control name as your namespace name is alse same.

Comment: This is not vb.net, so why did you add the tag?

Answer (score 1):

`MyWebBrowser` is the name of your form class and your code `MyWebBrowser.Navigate(textBox1.Text);` is trying to execute a static method in your class called `Navigate`, which you don't have. I think what you have is a WebBrowser control on your designer page. You need to replace `MyWebBrowser` with whatever name that control is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the webBrowser Object.

```
WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser1.Navigate("www.anyUrl.com");
```